# Expressing the probability of a random variable hitting a set in terms of its characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Is there a "nice" way to express the probability $\mathbb{P}(X \in A)$, where $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ in terms of the characteristic function of $X$? In case this is tricky in general, would it at least be possible for open convex sets or even just for Euclidean balls and random variables taking only finitely values (discrete)?

Comment: For a simple case see 'inversion formula' for characteristic functions.

Comment: That is did look at, but I cannot find anything apart from expressing the probability that a random variable belongs to a cube.

Comment: Sometimes the probability can be expressed as $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi_X(x) \hat \chi_A(x) dx$, where $\varphi_X$ is the characteristic function of $X$, $\hat \chi_A$ is the Fourier transform of the indicator function of $A$.

Comment: Are there any useful references that would tell me when such a representation is valid?